# Firebase topic-based push notifications and iOS QoS

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging, pubnub

For regular single-device push notifications through APNS, less important pushes can "replace" more important ones, because if the device is temporarily offline, only the last notification per device/app is retained and delivered with APNS.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW5

Let's say I'm delivering critical pushes to single devices, and informational, non-critical pushes via a topic-based pushes in Firebase FCM. **Would it still be true that the topic-based pushes could replace the critical pushes for an offline device?**

A predecessor of mine left behind a design document that said topic-bases push subscriptions would avoid the problem of informational pushes replacing critical ones, but I haven't found any documentation to support that. I'm thinking I might be better off using websockets or similar (maybe via PubNub) for the the informational pushes when the app is in the foreground, and only use APNS/FCM for the critical pushes. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

> disclaimer: this does not directly address the Firebase topic-based aspect of
> this question, rather, it provides an alternative solution that has
> the same features/implementation for both FCM and APNs with respect to QoS, or more specifically, the ability to retrieve messages that might have been missed while offline.

## Publish, Persist & Push with PubNub

### PubNub Storage Service

Well, putting APNs and FCM aside, PubNub will [persist all of your messages for later retrieval when you enable the Storage service](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/messages/storage). So when devices are offline, they can receive push notifications (APNs/FCM), and whether or not those notifications are received/acknowledged by the end-user, your app can easily retrieve all messages that were sent while the device was offline.

### PubNub Mobile Push Service

The other advantage of using PubNub is that you include [the APNs/FCM push payloads in the realtime publish payload](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/platform/messages/push/send) and if the device is active/online and subscribed to that channel, then it receives the message in realtime. If the device is not subscribed to the channel, it still receives the FCM/APNs push notification.

> NOTE: you must enable the Storage service on your PubNub key set and
> configure the retention as required: 1 day, 3 days, ... 30 days or
> Unlimited.